# How can I access protected member in QMouseEvent to get a float value of mouse position ? [Qt developers]

Tags: qt, inheritance, mouseevent, mouse-position, qmouseevent

`QMouseEvent` stores an integer value of the mouse position.
However, it has a protect member "s" which stores a float value of the mouse position.
How can I get the float value?

I have tried inheriting the `QMouseEvent`, but unfortunately I get this error message all the time.

> error: C2511: 'QMouseEventF::QMouseEventF(QWidget *)' : overloaded
>   member function not found in 'QMouseEventF'

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef QMOUSEEVENTF_H
#define QMOUSEEVENTF_H

#include<QMouseEvent>

class QMouseEventF : QMouseEvent
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
    QMouseEventF(QObject* parent = 0);

    ~QMouseEventF();
    qreal GetX();

};

#endif // QMOUSEEVENTF_H
```

And here is the inherited class:

```
#include "qmouseeventf.h"


QMouseEventF::QMouseEventF(QWidget *parent ): QMouseEvent(parent)
{

}


QMouseEventF::~QMouseEventF()
{

}


qreal QMouseEventF::GetX()
{
    return this->s.rx();
}
```

Comment: What about QMouseEvent::windowPos() and QMouseEvent::screenPos()? They are public

Comment: You are right, but they are integer value where I need the float value.
The float value is stored in a protected member.

Comment: Both return QPointF http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointf.html#setX. This is floating point precision

Comment: Thank you, I have tried using QPointF. It is used to store and return a float point of the mouse position. but unfortunately, even though it is defined as  a float type, in reality it stored an integer value .

Comment: It is completely normal since it is pixels. I am sure if you check in debugger your protected member s will have similar value.

Comment: I have done, it has a floating point precision (3 digits),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one, you have a different signature between header and source file because the header constructor is different than the source constructor. QMouseEvent does not inherit from QObject or QWidget.

Second, QMouseEvent does not take a QWidget * for a constructor.

Third, there is no need for the Q_OBJECT macro in the header.

Those are the reasons for correctness of the code. To answer your original question, it wouldn't make sense to use a float value since the integer value is what the mouse events operate with for pixel coordinates. If you need to convert it to float, do so yourself by casting.

Comment: Thank you, your advice helps me solving the error message, but in the same time it causes another issue! The mouseMoveEvent now does NOT fired!